# Use AWS SES, Route 53, CloudFlare and Lambda for an effective email solution for a Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, email, amazon-sns, cloudflare

I believe this question to be different form others because of the added Route53 complexity that is possibly contradicting the CLoudflare records.

I've recently moved to an AWS hosted service for a Wordpress site.

I'm using an EC2 instance with Bitnami installed, with Route 53 and Cloudflare dealing with the DNS records.

I should prefix all this by saying I'm quite new to this side of things and have followed multiple tutorials online.

Currently my site is working and functional.  Everything is being routed correctly, however mail is becoming an issue.

I would like anything@domain.co.uk to be forwarded to my personal email address, and in addition, I would like to be able to reply to that email address.

Steps taken so far:
EC2 - Site installed.
Route53 - Pointed NS Record to Cloudflare
Route53 - Pointed CNAME record to domain.co.uk
Cloudflare - Records are pointed back to EC2 ip.
-- this is the bit that works (I'm just adding all info)

SES - Domain has been registered and verified
*Both Route53 AND Cloudflare have the MX and TXT records (I'm not sure if this part is correct)
*MX points to inbound....amazonaws.com
*TXT is the string

SES - Email address has been added and verified (this is my personal address - I 'think' I need to verify a admin@domain.co.uk but those are not coming through.

SES - Rule Set - One configured to send emails to S3 and then notify of email via SNS (this was my last attempt to simply get some notification!)
Currently when I send an email to my domain I get a bounce back:

```
  To: myDomain <admin@domain.co.uk>
  Subject: sdfsdf

Your message cannot be delivered to the following recipients:

  Recipient address: admin@domain.co.uk
  Reason: Illegal host/domain name found
```

I have other rules set up and in place at a domain level for sending to SNS -> Lamba as a mail forwarder but for now I'd like to get the simplest part working :)

WP SES - this is the plugin for wordpress that has been installed.

I think that perhaps the duplicate records in Route53 and Cloudflare may be part o the problem but I'm not sure which one is correct.
TIA for any help.

Guides I've followed are:
https://wpforms.com/how-to-set-up-wordpress-smtp-using-amazon-ses/
https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/forwarding-emails-to-your-inbox-using-amazon-ses-2d261d60e417

Comment: I hope you find a solution, I want to do the same thing

Comment: @HarryMoreno - I think my solution needs to remove Cloudflare or spend some time learning about the intricacies involved.

Comment: I ended up punting and paying for zoho for business. It can handle mutliple emails (you only pay per zoho-user). protonmail is also $2/user/month and supports open source cryptography.

sadly I don't have the time to ramp up on serverless programming right now and most of the examples on are not maintained https://github.com/serverless/serverless#v1-projects